# Memory management using directors in SWIG C++ / Java

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am trying to create a Java wrapper for my C++ library using SWIG.
In order to get all the features I need within a Java programming environment, I need directors.
More specifically, I need Java users to be able to inherit from my C++ classes and implement certain methods.
In particular, one of the method that needs to be implemented is some sort of `clone()` method.

In C++, the user implementation provides an object pointer `Base*`. This pointer is then managed by the library itself.

```
Base* Derived::clone() {
  return new Derived(*this);
}
```

The problem I have with the Java wrapper is that the Java proxy class for `Base` acquires the management of the corresponding C++ director class `SwigDirector_Base`, by default.

This is certainly suitable in the general case, but not in this particular user-defined `clone()` function.

My personal constraint is that the Java wrapper for my C++ library uses no Java-specific code, so the user implementation should look like:

```
class Derived {
  ...
  Base clone() {
    return new Derived(this);
  }
}
```

So far, to make it work and avoid garbage collection of the copied Java instance, I have used the trick mentioned in http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp_memory_management_member_variables.

And to make sure that the Java `Derived` class never deletes the corresponding C++ director class `SwigDirector_Base`, I have used `%typemap(directorout)` to set the value of the Java cMemOwn flag of the copied instance from the C++ wrapper code, that is in method `SwigDirector_Base::clone()`.

I am not so happy with this solution as it applies to all methods returning a pointer to the `Base` class, whether it is a copy method or not...

Any idea on how to do this on a function-specific way? Or in any other way?

Comment: Can you give a more complete example perhaps? I.e. a minimal header file, interface file and Java required to show the problem? I'm slightly struggling to see the problem.